# DynamicData with EF6.1.2 does not work because of namespace changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-dynamic-data

Entity Framework 6.0 moved towards new namespaces. We can find the information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6

However, Dynamic Data seems to be expecting an ObjectContext from System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext (old namespace)...

Is there a way to get DynamicData to work with EF 6 ? Without using the Legacy ObjectContext system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, just use the updated components: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/28/announcing-the-release-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6.aspx